# purpose of run-parts(8) utility

Tags: bash, bash-script

At least under Debian-based systems, there is a `run-parts` utility in **debianutils** package which is used in various scripts. For example in /etc/X11/Xsession. It will run all the executable files found in a directory. Why is run-parts needed while one could use `find` with `-perm` option or `test` utility? In addition, what does `run-parts` consider as an executable file? Looks like it does not simply check the file permissions:

```
# run-parts --list --lsbsysinit /etc/X11/Xsession.d | tail -1
/etc/X11/Xsession.d/90x11-common_ssh-agent
# ls -l /etc/X11/Xsession.d/90x11-common_ssh-agent
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 629 2010-11-02 23:17 /etc/X11/Xsession.d/90x11-common_ssh-agent
# head /etc/X11/Xsession.d/90x11-common_ssh-agent
# $Id: 90x11-common_ssh-agent 305 2005-07-03 18:51:43Z dnusinow $

# This file is sourced by Xsession(5), not executed.

STARTSSH=
SSHAGENT=/usr/bin/ssh-agent
SSHAGENTARGS=

if has_option use-ssh-agent; then
  if [ -x "$SSHAGENT" ] && [ -z "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" ] \
#
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `find` instead of `run-parts`, there is no way to show which one is better. But I think using `run-parts` is shorter (less typing) and make your script more maintainable. An example is `/etc/crontab`:

```
# /etc/crontab: system-wide crontab
# Unlike any other crontab you don't have to run the `crontab'
# command to install the new version when you edit this file
# and files in /etc/cron.d. These files also have username fields,
# that none of the other crontabs do.

SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

# m h dom mon dow user  command
17 *    * * *   root    cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
25 6    * * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
47 6    * * 7   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly )
52 6    1 * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly )
```

For second question, you can find the answer in `debianutils` source code. In file `run-parts.c`, line 198:

```
/* Execute a file */                                                            
void run_part(char *progname)                                                   
{ 
     ....
     args[0] = progname;                                                         
     execv(progname, args);                                                      
     error("failed to exec %s: %s", progname, strerror(errno));                  
     exit(1);
     ....
}
```

You can see `run-parts` using `execv` system call. So if your file is not an binary execuable or an `Interpreter script`, `execv` can not run the file.

**Note**

- What is `Interpreter script`:

From `man execve`, section `Interpreter scripts`:

```
Interpreter scripts
       An  interpreter  script  is  a  text  file  that has execute permission
       enabled and whose first line is of the form:

           #! interpreter [optional-arg]

       The interpreter must be a valid pathname for an executable which is not
       itself  a  script.   If  the filename argument of execve() specifies an
       interpreter script, then interpreter will be invoked with the following
       arguments:

           interpreter [optional-arg] filename arg...

       where arg...  is the series of words pointed to by the argv argument of
       execve().

       For portable use, optional-arg should either be absent, or be specified
       as  a  single word (i.e., it should not contain white space); see NOTES
       below.
```

- You can see debianutils source code [here](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/precise/debianutils/precise/view/head:/run-parts.c).

Comment: Thank you for such exhaustive answer! However, `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/90x11-common_ssh-agent` has not executable permissions nor does it begin with shebang and pathname for interpreter. Why is it found by `run-parts` as I showed in example in my initial post?

Comment: No, it is sourced by `Xsession`, not for executing.

Comment: @Gnouc I'm aware of this, but I was surprised that `run-parts` found such files until I learned that `--list` will list non-executable files as well.

Answer (score 3):

The files that `run-parts` runs are fairly well documented. In addition to them being executable, the following man page snippet explains the requirements:

```
If  neither  the --lsbsysinit option nor the --regex option is given then the
names must consist entirely of ASCII upper- and lower-case letters, ASCII digits,
ASCII underscores, and ASCII minus-hyphens.

If the --lsbsysinit option is given, then the names must not end in .dpkg-old  or
.dpkg-dist or .dpkg-new or .dpkg-tmp, and must belong to one or more  of  the 
following  namespaces:  the  LANANA-assigned  namespace  (^[a-z0-9]+$); the LSB
hierarchical and reserved namespaces (^_?([a-z0-9_.]+-)+[a-z0-9]+$); and the
Debian cron script namespace (^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+$)
```

Using the `--lsbsysinit` option is particularly useful for running scripts in `/etc` since many of the scripts will be listed as conffiles in their respective packages. A common case where files with the `dpkg-*` extension are created is when changes have been made to the installed version and `dpkg` tries to install a new version. `dpkg` will usually store the version the user didn't choose in the same directory. Using `run-parts` is a good, standard way to ensure that none of these extensions or any others which are not meant to be run aren't. It reduces the chances of bugs appearing because a developer forgot to include one of these in their script.

Even without the `--lsbsysinit`, it is still a useful command to reduce the amount of code that needs to be written and improve reliability when used throughout the system. Though not quite so much as it is easier to replace with a `find ... -executable -exec {} ;` or the like.

Comment: I don't feel `--lsbsysinit` is very useful. You still can't use `file.ext`. If you examine the regex carefully, you will see that it requires a `-` after the last `.` So you could use `file.-ext`, but that's awful.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> Why is run-parts needed while one could use find 
> with -perm option or test utility?
> ```

This is simply by design. As you can see on the man page, `run-parts` has also a number of options. All the things could also be written in shell.

[Edit]

It is also likely it was implemented in C to prevent hacking.

Answer (score 0):

Straight to the title of the question (from `man run-parts`):

```
run scripts or programs in a directory

    run-parts  runs  all  the  executable files named within constraints described
    below, found in directory directory.  Other files and directories are silently ignored.
```

When it comes to `cron` jobs, it provides an easy way of executing a set of scripts from a directory, on a certain schedule. The same applies if you're going to manually run a set of scripts, with a single command:

```
ivanleoncz@ilex: /tmp $ ll scripts/
total 12
-rwxrw-r-- 1 ivanleoncz ivanleoncz 27 Jun 15 18:29 script_1*
-rwxrw-r-- 1 ivanleoncz ivanleoncz 27 Jun 15 18:29 script_2*
-rwxrw-r-- 1 ivanleoncz ivanleoncz 27 Jun 15 18:30 script_3*

ivanleoncz@ilex: /tmp $ cat scripts/script_1
#!/bin/bash
echo "I'm $0."

ivanleoncz@ilex: /tmp $ cat scripts/script_2
#!/bin/bash
echo "I'm $0."

ivanleoncz@ilex: /tmp $ cat scripts/script_3
#!/bin/bash
echo "I'm $0."

ivanleoncz@ilex: /tmp $ run-parts scripts
I'm scripts/script_1.
I'm scripts/script_2.
I'm scripts/script_3.

ivanleoncz@ilex: /tmp $ run-parts --report scripts
scripts/script_1:
I'm scripts/script_1.
scripts/script_2:
I'm scripts/script_2.
scripts/script_3:
I'm scripts/script_3.
```

The following conditions (some quite normal on shellscripting) are required for the scripts:

1. Exec permission for UGO (User|Group|Others), depending on where the user fits.
2. Shebang at the top of the script, telling which shell is going to be used on its execution.
3. Must have no file extensions. That's quirky, but yes, it is required.